# Sequelize get data of another column while using Aggregate Function

Tags: node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js

I'm trying to get data using **Sequelize** in my **Express** app and I'm using **SQL Server** as database.

Here is my code:

```
Order.findAll({
    attributes:[
        [Sequelize.fn('SUM', Sequelize.col('total_price')), 'total_price'],
    ],
    include:[
        {model: Customer, attributes:['name']}
    ],
    group:['Customer.id','Customer.name']
}).then(result =>res.json(result))
```

This code is running well, and successfully returns the data with *aggregate function*. But when I did added another attribute like `'product_id', 'status', 'expired_date'` that doesn't need aggregation, it returns me an error like

> Column 'Customer.product_id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Based on this [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1110163/SQL-GROUP-By-and-the-Column-name-is-invalid-in-the), it only can get columns which are in the GROUP BY list.

But how is the best way get the added attribute and the aggregation result? Like:

```
{
     'total_price': 2000,
     'name': 'Jack',
     'status': 'Paid'
}
```

Should do 2 get data in a function, like first I get the aggregate, and then get another data. I'm worried there are possibilities return unrelated data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found a way to do that, I only added the attribute/column that I want to get into  the **group_by** clause. Just like this:

```
Order.findAll({
attributes:[
    'product_id', 'status', 'expired_date',
    [Sequelize.fn('SUM', Sequelize.col('total_price')), 'total_price'],
],
include:[
    {model: Customer, attributes:['name']}
],
group:['Customer.id','Customer.name','Order.product_id', 'Order.status', 'Order.expired_date']
}).then(result =>res.json(result))
```

It's successfully returns my expected result. But I don't know is there any consideration if do it like this? Thanks

Comment: How do I get these columns that I was not grouped??